# Ubuntu 17.04 wifi belkin USB adapter install?

Tags: wireless

How can I make my wireless USB adapter work?

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 050d:110a belkin Components F9L1101v2 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8192DU]
```

Answer (score 2):

Larry Finger has source code on github.com for this device.  If you have a working internet connection on the computer

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192du
sudo dkms install 8192du/1.0
```

Reboot

Comment: Works as well on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal (tested with Belkin N300 adapter).